# spservices not working in updatepanel

Tags: spservices, updatepanel, cascading

I have a piece of code which is inside a dropdown change event. This dropdown is inside an update panel as i want it to happen async.

Now I have a `SPServices.CascadeDropdowns` also binded to the dropdown. As soon as I bind this, the dropdown change event does not trigger.

Can anyone throw some light as to what is going wrong here.

I am not expecting a solution but want to know if my approach is incorrect.

Comment: You need to add code for us to find out whats wrong with it :)

Answer (score 1):

I should use the example that are explained in the SPServices project, like this:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems

basically you can use JQuery and IMHO is better